# Ibm bluemix timeout after 60sec

Tags: cloud, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-functions

I try to run a loop for 1000 times, when the program reaches 60 seconds typing this error

```
Internal Server Error
```

Sample code

```
for i in range(1000,0,-1):
    wc = fun_A(funInput) #function
    time.sleep(i/1000)
```

Εrror is only when reach the 60sec.
I try for a repetition number of less than 60sec and runs normally

Answer (score 4, accepted):

60 seconds is the limit for a serverless action on IBM Cloud. You can find the details here - https://console.bluemix.net/docs/openwhisk/openwhisk_reference.html#openwhisk_syslimits. There is also information there about how to request more time for your action (scroll down to "Increasing fixed limits").